# Set X Axis of vb chart to week numbers

Tags: vb.net, charts

I am trying to use week numbers on the x axis of a vb chart.

The week numbers are stored as integers in an SQL table.

My current settings are below

```
Dim sw as integer    
Dim ew as integer    
ew = DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Date.Today, FirstDayOfWeek.Monday, 
FirstWeekOfYear.FirstFourDays) + 1
sw = ew -6    
ChartStopsByDate.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = sw    
ChartStopsByDate.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = ew    
ChartStopsByDate.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1    
ChartStopsByDate.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Minimum = 0    
ChartStopsByDate.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum = 60    
ChartStopsByDate.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Interval = 10
```

Was working fine until the year end and now in axis intervals of `-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1`
I actually need `49,50,51,52,53,1`

Any help most welcome

Comment: What does `sw` and `ew` means? And why `sw = ew - 6`?

Comment: Why you added +1 to current week? Why you after that subtract -6 from current week? Your code will probably work correct in february :) Just write what you try to acheive.